# iPhone hotspot throughput slower than WiFi speed?

Tags: iphone, network, wifi, performance, internet

I am running a "**hotspot** ---*wifi*---> **router** ---*ethernet*---> **device**" network config and speeds are slower than native phone 5G speed.

Here are some test results:

iPhone 12 mini: 1Gpbs+

Config: 220-500Mbit/s (mostly hovering around 240Mbit/s)

The "**hotspot** ---*wifi*---> **router**" part is 2x2 Mimo 80Mhz WiFi 5, so theoretical max is 867Mbit/s, practical ~640Mbit/s (verified with iperf3 testing). Signal is not the issue (phone position consistent in both tests), WiFi signal 100% strength 3 meters away unobstructed.
Any ideas?